# Проверка строки на опрелеленные символы

Tags: python, строки

Пользователь вводит строку и мы должны сравнить все символы в строке со списком разрешенных символов. Если все символы разрешены то возвращаем True, если нет то False. Не очень понимаю как это можно реализовать.

```
def secure_eval(action):
is_true = 0
allowed = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '*', '/']
for i in range(len(action)):
    if allowed in action[i]:
        is_true=1
    else:
        is_true=0
        break

if is_true:
    return eval(action)
else:
    return "Я не могу выполнить данную команду"
```

Ошибка:

```
line 9, in secure_eval
    if allowed in action[i]:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141739/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрались с вами в комментариях, что проблем было две:

1. Когда встречается символ, которого нет среди разрешенных нужно сразу прерывать работу функции, поскольку последующие разрешенные элементы будут перезаписывать значение переменной `is_true`
2. Оператор `in` применим сразу к целому списку, поэтому нет необходимости писать вложенные циклы.

С учетом вышесказанного должен был получиться следующий код:

```
def secure_eval(action):
    is_true = 0
    allowed = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '*', '/']
    for i in range(len(action)):
        if action[i] in allowed:
            is_true = 1
        else:
            is_true = 0
            break
    if is_true:
        return eval(action)
    else:
        return "Я не могу выполнить данную команду"
```

И хотя этот код работает, в образовательных целях покажу вам, как можно было решить эту задачу более оптимально:

```
allowed = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '-', '*', '/']

def secure_eval(action):
    if not any([letter for letter in action if letter not in allowed]):
        return eval(action)
    return "Я не могу выполнить данную команду"
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку речь о множествах, то наиболее эффективно решать эту задачу можно через множества, а именно через метод `.issuperset()`, возвращающий истину, если одно множество является надмножеством для другого.

```
def secure_eval(action):
    return eval(action) if set('0123456789+-*/').issuperset(action) else "Я не могу выполнить данную команду"
```

При этом остается вероятность ошибки вычисления выражения, если оно, например, такое: `1++1-22--`.
Чтобы не получить неожиданную ошибку, я бы предложил обработать ошибки внутри функции:

```
def secure_eval2(action):
    try:
        if not set('0123456789+-*/').issuperset(action):
            raise SyntaxError
        return eval(action)
    except Exception:
        return "Я не могу выполнить данную команду"
```

Тест функции `secure_eval2()`:

```
for txt in "1+2-3*4", "4+5-A+1", "1++1-22--":
    print(f'{txt} = {secure_eval2(txt)}')
```

```
1+2-3*4 = -9
4+5-A+1 = Я не могу выполнить данную команду
1++1-22-- = Я не могу выполнить данную команду
```

Функция `secure_eval()` на таком тестовом наборе данных выдает ошибку, а `secure_eval2()` отрабатывает штатно.